# i am developing a registration form in laravel but when the submit button is clicked it wont redirect to my login page why is that?

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

once user clicked on the submit button the page should be redirected to login page but it wont happen here

my registration controller code is as follows

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
//use App\Login;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


class RegistrationController extends Controller
{
    public function show()
    {
        // echo "ddd";
        // echo "ddd";
        return view('registration/registration');
    }

    public function register()
    {       
       $user=new user;
       $user->fname = Input::get('fname');
       $user->lname = Input::get('lname');
       $user->mail = Input::get('mail');      
       $user->pwd =Input::get('pwd');
       $user->save();
       return Redirect::to('login');
    }
}
```

here is my registration form code  is as follows

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<style>
    .bod{
        background-color:#f8f8f8;
        border-width:5px;
        margin-top:-12px;
    }
    .logoImg{
        height:70px;
        width:150px;
        margin-top:40px;
        /*margin-left:125px;*/
    }
    .form{
        background-color:white;
        height: 422px;
        width: 382px;
        margin-left: 475px;
    }
    .txtbox{
        width:333px;
    }
    .bttn{
        width:333px;

    }
    .lbl{
        width:100px;
    }
    .col-md-3 {
        -webkit-box-flex: 0;
        -ms-flex: 0 0 25%;
        flex: 0 7 45%;
        max-width: 172px;
    }
    .radio{
        border:1px solid blue;
    }


    input[type="radio"] {
        -ms-transform: scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: scale(1.5);
        border: 2px solid white;

    }

    input[type='radio']:checked:after {
        width: 5px;
        height: 5px;
        border-radius: 10px;

        position: relative;
        background-color: blue;
        content: '';
        display: inline-block;
        visibility: visible;
        border: 1px solid black;

    }


</style>
</head>
<body class="bod">
<center><img class="logoImg" src="img/logo.png" /></center>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-8">
            <form action="{{ route('register') }}" method="post"  class="form">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div style="margin-left:12px">
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline col-md-5" >
                    <input class="form-check-input  " type="radio" name="Personal_account" id="Personal_account" value="Personal_account">
                    <label class="form-check-label " for="Personal_account">Personal account</label>
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline col-md-5">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="Buisness account" id="Buisness account" value="Buisness account">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3">Buisness account</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row" style="margin-left:8px">
                <div class="form-group col-md-3 divname">
                    <label for="inputEmail4">First name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control " id="fname" name="fname">
                    <div style="color:red" id="fname_error">Invalid First Name</div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3 divname">
                    <label for="inputPassword4">Last name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname">
                    <div style="color:red" id="lname_error">Invalid last Name</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-7">
                <label for="inputAddress" class="lbl">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control txtbox" id="mail" name="mail">
                <div style="color:red" id="mail_error">Invalid Email</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-7">
                <label for="inputAddress2">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control txtbox" id="pwd" name="pwd">
                <div style="color:red" id="pwd_error">Password required</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-7">
                <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary bttn" id="reg" name="reg" value ="Register">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#fname_error").hide();
        $("#lname_error").hide();
        $("#mail_error").hide();
        $("#pwd_error").hide();
    });


    $( "#reg" ).click(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var status = true;
        var name = $("#fname").val();
        var lname = $("#lname").val();
        var pwd = $("#pwd").val();
        var mail = $("#mail").val();

        if(name == ''){
            status = false;
            $("#fname_error").show();
            $("#fname").css("border","2px solid red");
        }
        else{
            $("#fname").css("border","1px solid green");
            $("#fname_error").hide();
        }


        if(lname == '')
        {
            status = false;
            $("#lname_error").show();
            $("#lname").css("border","2px solid red");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#lname_error").hide();
            $("#lname").css("border","1px solid green");


        }


        if(mail == '')
        {
            status = false;
            $("#mail_error").show();
            $("#mail").css("border","2px solid red");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#mail").css("border","1px solid green");
            $("#mail_error").hide();

        }


        if(pwd == '')
        {
            status = false;
            $("#pwd_error").show();
            $("#pwd").css("border","2px solid red");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#pwd").css("border","1px solid green");
            $("#pwd_error").hide();

        }

        if(status){
            $("#register").submit();
        }
    });
</script>


</body>

</html>
```

my route are define like this

```
Route::get('/','LoginController@show');
//Route::get('/login','LoginController@show')->name('login');
Route::get('/home','HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::post('/login','LoginController@login')->name('login');
Route::get('/registration','RegistrationController@show');
Route::post('/registration','RegistrationController@register')->name('register');
```

once user clicked on the button the data should be saved to db and it has to navigate to the login page? but here it wont navigate the page is still in the registration page

Comment: Next time, take some time to format your question properly.

Comment: sure thank u very much

Comment: Does your user record gets saved??

Comment: yess in addition to that i forgot to give the name and id for the form,now it is working

Answer (score 0):

You can try  like this,

```
return redirect()->route('login');
```

Comment: no it wont work also the data is not stored in the database

Comment: i always use this way and it work, if you need to store data you can adding $user, for example return redirect()->route('login', ['user' => $user]);

Comment: yess in addition to that i forgot to give the name and id for the form,now it is working

Answer (score 0):

You are not importing your user model in your controller

```
use App\User;
```

Comment: yess in addition to that i forgot to give the name and id for the form,now it is working